# Update Azerothcore with latest updates from master branch

Tags: azerothcore

I am currently running Azerothcore via docker on my centos 7 server. I am trying to update it with the updates since i originally set it up.

current docker version:
`Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe`

current docker-compose version:
`docker-compose version 1.18.0, build 8dd22a9`

Here is the build command i ran:
`./bin/acore-docker-build`

When i run the docker build command i am getting the following errors:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.253GB
Step 1/11 : FROM ubuntu:bionic
 ---> 2eb2d388e1a2
Step 2/11 : RUN apt update && apt install -y git cmake make gcc g++ clang libmysqlclient-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libncurses-dev libace-6.* libace-dev
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0faa7371eddb
Step 3/11 : ADD .git /azerothcore/.git
 ---> 2ab1c86cbb7b
Step 4/11 : ADD deps /azerothcore/deps
 ---> 789597de6023
Step 5/11 : ADD conf/config.cmake.dist /azerothcore/conf/config.cmake.dist
 ---> eca4d1db86c9
Step 6/11 : ADD src /azerothcore/src
 ---> 6d28275a2563
Step 7/11 : ADD modules /azerothcore/modules
 ---> 1cc8619b8f6c
Step 8/11 : ADD CMakeLists.txt /azerothcore/CMakeLists.txt
 ---> 35be47131ae7
Step 9/11 : ARG ENABLE_SCRIPTS=1
 ---> Running in c03d0e691bfc
Removing intermediate container c03d0e691bfc
 ---> 919385a33592
Step 10/11 : ENV ENABLE_SCRIPTS=$ENABLE_SCRIPTS
 ---> Running in dbd11cdd7f3e
Removing intermediate container dbd11cdd7f3e
 ---> 7c5f40359309
Step 11/11 : ENTRYPOINT  cd azerothcore/build &&             cmake ../ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/azeroth-server -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++ -DTOOLS=0 -DSCRIPTS=$ENABLE_SCRIPTS -DWITH_WARNINGS=1 -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-Werror" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-Werror" &&             MTHREADS=`grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo`; MTHREADS=$(($MTHREADS + 2)) &&             make -j $MTHREADS &&             make install -j $MTHREADS &&             cp /azeroth-server/bin/worldserver /binworldserver &&             cp /azeroth-server/bin/authserver /binauthserver
 ---> Running in 90f184b54b10
Removing intermediate container 90f184b54b10
 ---> 2bf702b4c10a
Successfully built 2bf702b4c10a
Successfully tagged acbuild:latest
Loading module: modules/mod-individual-xp-master
Loading module: modules/mod-autobalance-master
Loading module: modules/mod-ah-bot-master
-- Running cmake hook: AFTER_LOAD_CONF
-- No hooks registered for AFTER_LOAD_CONF
-- Enabled С++17 support
-- Detected 64-bit platform
-- UNIX: Using jemalloc
-- UNIX: Using default configuration directory
-- UNIX: Using default library directory
-- UNIX: Configuring uninstall target
-- UNIX: Created uninstall target
-- UNIX: Detected compiler: /usr/bin/clang
-- Clang: All warnings enabled
-- Running cmake hook: AFTER_LOAD_CMAKE_MODULES
-- No hooks registered for AFTER_LOAD_CMAKE_MODULES
-- cotire 1.8.0 loaded.
-- Found ACE library: /usr/lib/libACE.so
-- Found ACE headers: /usr/include
-- Using mysql-config: /usr/bin/mysql_config
-- Found MySQL library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so
-- Found MySQL headers: /usr/include/mysql
-- Found git binary : /usr/bin/git

* AzerothCore revision            : b21f1337757e+ 2020-07-23 22:15:20 -0700 (master branch)
* AzerothCore buildtype           : Release

* Install core to                 : /azeroth-server
* Install libraries to            : /azeroth-server/lib
* Install configs to              : /azeroth-server/etc

* Build world/auth                : Yes (default)
* Build with scripts              : Yes (default)
* Build map/vmap tools            : No  (default)
* Build core w/PCH                : Yes (default)
* Build scripts w/PCH             : Yes (default)
* Show all warnings               : Yes
* Use coreside debug              : No  (default)
* Use unix gperftools             : No  (default)
* Use GIT revision hash           : Yes (default)
* Enable extra features           : Yes (default)
* Enable vmap DisableMgr checks   : Yes (default)
* Enable extra logging functions  : No (default)
* Show source tree                : No (For UNIX default)

-- Found Readline library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so
-- Include dir is: /usr/include
-- Running cmake hook: BEFORE_SRC_LOAD
-- No hooks registered for BEFORE_SRC_LOAD
-- Running cmake hook: BEFORE_GAME_LIBRARY
-- No hooks registered for BEFORE_GAME_LIBRARY
-- Running cmake hook: AFTER_GAME_LIBRARY
Including /azerothcore/modules/mod-ah-bot-master/cmake/after_game_lib.cmake
-- Running cmake hook: AFTER_AUTHSERVER_CMAKE
-- No hooks registered for AFTER_AUTHSERVER_CMAKE
-- Running cmake hook: BEFORE_SCRIPTS_LIBRARY
-- No hooks registered for BEFORE_SCRIPTS_LIBRARY
-- SCRIPT PREPARATIONS
  -> Prepared: Spells
  -> Prepared: Commands
  -> Prepared: World
  -> Prepared: Outdoor PVP Zones
  -> Prepared: Eastern Kingdoms
  -> Prepared: Kalimdor
  -> Prepared: Outland
  -> Prepared: Northrend
  -> Prepared: Events
  -> Prepared: Pet

-- SCRIPT PREPARATION COMPLETE
-- Running cmake hook: AFTER_WORLDSERVER_CMAKE
-- No hooks registered for AFTER_WORLDSERVER_CMAKE
-- Running cmake hook: AFTER_SRC_LOAD
-- No hooks registered for AFTER_SRC_LOAD
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /azerothcore/build
Scanning dependencies of target fmt
Scanning dependencies of target Recast
Scanning dependencies of target Detour
Scanning dependencies of target gsoap
[  0%] Building CXX object deps/recastnavigation/Recast/CMakeFiles/Recast.dir/Source/Recast.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object deps/fmt/CMakeFiles/fmt.dir/fmt/format.cc.o
[  0%] Building CXX object deps/recastnavigation/Detour/CMakeFiles/Detour.dir/Source/DetourAlloc.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object deps/gsoap/CMakeFiles/gsoap.dir/soapC.cpp.o
Scanning dependencies of target g3dlib
[  0%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/AABox.cpp.o
Scanning dependencies of target jemalloc
[  0%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/arena.c.o
[  0%] Building CXX object deps/recastnavigation/Detour/CMakeFiles/Detour.dir/Source/DetourAssert.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object deps/recastnavigation/Detour/CMakeFiles/Detour.dir/Source/DetourCommon.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object deps/recastnavigation/Recast/CMakeFiles/Recast.dir/Source/RecastAlloc.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object deps/recastnavigation/Recast/CMakeFiles/Recast.dir/Source/RecastAssert.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object deps/recastnavigation/Detour/CMakeFiles/Detour.dir/Source/DetourNavMesh.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object deps/recastnavigation/Recast/CMakeFiles/Recast.dir/Source/RecastArea.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/Any.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object deps/recastnavigation/Recast/CMakeFiles/Recast.dir/Source/RecastContour.cpp.o
[  2%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/background_thread.c.o
[  2%] Building CXX object deps/gsoap/CMakeFiles/gsoap.dir/soapServer.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object deps/recastnavigation/Detour/CMakeFiles/Detour.dir/Source/DetourNavMeshBuilder.cpp.o
[  2%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/base.c.o
[  2%] Building CXX object deps/recastnavigation/Detour/CMakeFiles/Detour.dir/Source/DetourNavMeshQuery.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object deps/gsoap/CMakeFiles/gsoap.dir/stdsoap2.cpp.o
[  2%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/bin.c.o
[  2%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/bitmap.c.o
[  2%] Building CXX object deps/recastnavigation/Recast/CMakeFiles/Recast.dir/Source/RecastFilter.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/BinaryFormat.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object deps/recastnavigation/Detour/CMakeFiles/Detour.dir/Source/DetourNode.cpp.o
[  3%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/ckh.c.o
[  3%] Building CXX object deps/recastnavigation/Recast/CMakeFiles/Recast.dir/Source/RecastLayers.cpp.o
[  3%] Linking CXX static library libDetour.a
[  3%] Built target Detour
[  3%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/BinaryInput.cpp.o
[  3%] Built target revision.h
[  3%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/BinaryOutput.cpp.o
[  3%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/ctl.c.o
[  3%] Building CXX object deps/recastnavigation/Recast/CMakeFiles/Recast.dir/Source/RecastMesh.cpp.o
[  3%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/div.c.o
[  3%] Building CXX object deps/recastnavigation/Recast/CMakeFiles/Recast.dir/Source/RecastMeshDetail.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/Box.cpp.o
[  3%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/extent.c.o
[  3%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/Capsule.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/CollisionDetection.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/CoordinateFrame.cpp.o
[  3%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/extent_dss.c.o
[  3%] Building CXX object deps/fmt/CMakeFiles/fmt.dir/fmt/posix.cc.o
[  4%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/extent_mmap.c.o
[  4%] Linking CXX static library libgsoap.a
[  4%] Building CXX object deps/recastnavigation/Recast/CMakeFiles/Recast.dir/Source/RecastRasterization.cpp.o
[  4%] Built target gsoap
[  5%] Building CXX object deps/recastnavigation/Recast/CMakeFiles/Recast.dir/Source/RecastRegion.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/Crypto.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/Cylinder.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/debugAssert.cpp.o
[  6%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/hash.c.o
[  6%] Linking CXX static library libfmt.a
[  6%] Built target fmt
[  6%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/hook.c.o
[  6%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/FileSystem.cpp.o
[  6%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/jemalloc.c.o
[  6%] Building CXX object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/jemalloc_cpp.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/fileutils.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/format.cpp.o
[  6%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/large.c.o
[  6%] Linking CXX static library libRecast.a
[  6%] Built target Recast
[  6%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/log.c.o
[  6%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/g3dfnmatch.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/g3dmath.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/Line.cpp.o
[  6%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/malloc_io.c.o
[  6%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/LineSegment.cpp.o
[  6%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/mutex.c.o
[  6%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/mutex_pool.c.o
[  6%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/Log.cpp.o
[  7%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/nstime.c.o
[  7%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/pages.c.o
[  7%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/prng.c.o
[  7%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/Matrix3.cpp.o
[  8%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/Matrix4.cpp.o
[  8%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/prof.c.o
[  8%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/rtree.c.o
[  8%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/safety_check.c.o
[  8%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/MemoryManager.cpp.o
[  8%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/stats.c.o
[  8%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/sc.c.o
[  8%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/sz.c.o
[  9%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/tcache.c.o
[  9%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/PhysicsFrame.cpp.o
[  9%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/test_hooks.c.o
[  9%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/ticker.c.o
[  9%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/tsd.c.o
[  9%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/Plane.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/prompt.cpp.o
[  9%] Building C object deps/jemalloc/CMakeFiles/jemalloc.dir/src/witness.c.o
[  9%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/Quat.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/Random.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/Ray.cpp.o
[  9%] Linking CXX static library libjemalloc.a
[  9%] Built target jemalloc
[  9%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/ReferenceCount.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/RegistryUtil.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/Sphere.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/stringutils.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/System.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/TextOutput.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/TextInput.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/Triangle.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/uint128.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/UprightFrame.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/Vector2.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/Vector3.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object deps/g3dlite/CMakeFiles/g3dlib.dir/source/Vector4.cpp.o
[ 11%] Linking CXX static library libg3dlib.a
[ 11%] Built target g3dlib
Scanning dependencies of target shared
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/server/shared/CMakeFiles/shared.dir/Network/RealmSocket.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/server/shared/CMakeFiles/shared.dir/DataStores/DBCStore.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/server/shared/CMakeFiles/shared.dir/DataStores/DBCDatabaseLoader.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/server/shared/CMakeFiles/shared.dir/Realms/RealmList.cpp.o
[ 12%] Linking CXX static library libshared.a
[ 12%] Built target shared
[ 12%] Generating CXX prefix source src/common/cotire/common_CXX_prefix.cxx
[ 12%] Generating CXX prefix header src/common/cotire/common_CXX_prefix.hxx
[ 12%] Building CXX precompiled header src/common/cotire/common_CXX_prefix.hxx.pch
Scanning dependencies of target common
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/Collision/BoundingIntervalHierarchy.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/Collision/Management/MMapFactory.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/Collision/DynamicTree.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/Common.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/GitRevision.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/Collision/Management/MMapManager.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/Collision/Management/VMapFactory.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/Collision/Management/VMapManager2.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/Collision/Maps/MapTree.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/Collision/Maps/TileAssembler.cpp.o
In file included from /azerothcore/src/common/Collision/Management/VMapManager2.cpp:29:
In file included from /azerothcore/src/server/game/DataStores/DBCStores.h:11:
/azerothcore/src/common/DataStores/DBCStore.h:46:43: fatal error: use of undeclared identifier 'FT_SQL_PRESENT'
                if ((*formatString)[x] == FT_SQL_PRESENT)
                                          ^
1 error generated.
src/common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/build.make:252: recipe for target 'src/common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/Collision/Management/VMapManager2.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/Collision/Management/VMapManager2.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/Collision/Models/GameObjectModel.cpp.o
In file included from /azerothcore/src/common/Collision/Models/GameObjectModel.cpp:18:
In file included from /azerothcore/src/server/game/DataStores/DBCStores.h:11:
/azerothcore/src/common/DataStores/DBCStore.h:46:43: fatal error: use of undeclared identifier 'FT_SQL_PRESENT'
                if ((*formatString)[x] == FT_SQL_PRESENT)
                                          ^
1 error generated.
src/common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/build.make:327: recipe for target 'src/common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/Collision/Models/GameObjectModel.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/Collision/Models/GameObjectModel.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:755: recipe for target 'src/common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/all' failed
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Is this an issue with the updates from the master branch or is there other issue going on?

Comment: @Iocus313 do you have any customizations? something that you changed in the code? or it's 100% clean AzerothCore?

Comment: I do have 3 modules added currently. Individual xp, autobalance and ah-bot. But no other customization's

Comment: @FrancescoBorzi i just did a test of reverting this commit in my fork:
[https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/commit/833611f1c5e43bb9c13c579962eedbf3b4ab87aa](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/commit/833611f1c5e43bb9c13c579962eedbf3b4ab87aa)
after doing so, the build is working again.

Comment: @Iocus have you tried a clean build? i.e. run this first then try again `bin/acore-docker-remove-build-cache`

Comment: @FrancescoBorzi yes i did try clearing the build cache using that script before i tried to revert the commit. But i still got the same build errors.

Comment: @FrancescoBorzi i rebased my fork with the current master branch. Removed all the files in the src directory. Then did a git hard reset. Then ran git pull. Ran the remove build cache script again. Then kicked off another build. Build is working fine again with the current master branch. So i am guessing the issue was with my src directory not being in sync with the fork repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i rebased my fork with the current master branch. Removed all the files in the src directory. Then did a git hard reset. Then ran git pull. Ran the remove build cache script again. Then kicked off another build. Build is working fine again with the current master branch. So i am guessing the issue was with my src directory not being in sync with the fork repo.